# How to ignore App Tab when navigating with Ctrl+Tab in Firefox 16?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

After pinning a tab as app tab in Firefox 16, I do not like it to be "in the way" when navigating through the other tabs using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Scenario: I open an online radio channel, want to keep the music playing in an app tab, thus do not need the app tab in the navigation anymore.

Unfortunately, I could neither find an `about:config` setup nor a plugin for that.

Comment: Sorry. I work on the Firefox Project, and there is no direct way to skip it. It is possible that there is an extension for it though. You should check here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/extensions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there are no native options of the behaviour you require.

Solution: Install [AppTabs Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/apptabs-plus/), tick the options box that says "Exclude from tab-switching".